# Android - Attach image to E-mail

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent, email-attachments

I am working on a feedback feature within my app, the user is supposed to select an image from the gallery and type his message and press send, on send button click the code is supposed to to get the text from the box (figure below) and attach it to the email intent and send the whole thing, everything seems to work just fine until I get the "can't attach empty file" toast message, this is how far I got in the code

```
 String rating = String.valueOf(RateBar.getRating());
            String subject = Feedback.getText().toString();
            String FileLocation = FilePathPreview.getText().toString();
            String to ="EngNor.supp@gmail.com";
            String message = UserInput.getText().toString();
            String body = "Rating : "+rating+" out of 5"+
                    "\n "+message;
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/"+FileLocation));

            //need this to prompts email client only
            email.setType("message/rfc822");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

---

```
public void grabImg(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String PathP = selectedImage.getPath().toString();
            FilePathPreview.setText(PathP);
        }
}
```

[image: Feedback activity]

Comment: I guess pre-pending the `file:/` is what's breaking your code. Try getting rid of that.

Comment: `String PathP = selectedImage.getPath().toString();` is useless, unless perhaps the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`. Also, bear in mind that `ACTION_SEND` supports *either* `EXTRA_TEXT` *or* `EXTRA_STREAM`, not necessarily both.

Comment: `String FileLocation = FilePathPreview.getText().toString();` You did not tell whats in it. You should of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a globale `Uri` variable then save the uri in `onActivityResult()`

```
Uri uri = null;

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            uri  = selectedImage; // here set the uri 
            String PathP = selectedImage.getPath().toString();
            FilePathPreview.setText(PathP);
        }
}
```

then pass the same `uri` variable to

```
        //....
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        //....
        //need this to prompts email client only
        email.setType("message/rfc822");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

**Update:** Add this flag if you still cant share

`email.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`

Comment: The `Intent` probably also needs to have `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` added as a flag. The `ACTION_SEND` implementation may not have rights to the `Uri` otherwise.

Comment: @CommonsWare please provide code how and where to add the permission

Comment: @CommonsWare he should have read storage permission when he is picking image ....does he still  need `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` ?

Comment: @SígvardrÓlavrsson try the code with updated answer.

Comment: @SohailZahid: "does he still need FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION ?" -- you are assuming that `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` matters here. The OP is using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. That can return **any sort of `Uri`** that the implementer of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` wants. That includes content served by `FileProvider` or other types of `ContentProvider` that are not secured via `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. The OP's app will get rights to use that `Uri`, but only via `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` can the OP transfer those rights to another app.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
 Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
 String PathP;
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, null, null, null, null);
 if(cursor != null)
 {
     cursor.moveToFirst(); 
     int idx =cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
     PathP = cursor.getString(idx);
     cursor.close();
 }
```